# Services that get facebook emails

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I've noticed that my android phone, the iphone, outlook.com, and yahoo mail all can import my friends' email addresses (and sometimes phone numbers) from facebook. However, I don't see anywhere in the documentation of the API to suggest that you can get email.

Do these services have special agreements with Facebook or am I just not finding the specific api for "contact" importing? I've not had any luck using "email" field with friends api.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These services have some special agreements with Facebook and thus are able to retrieve the Email Ids of the Friends of the User. Most of them don't allow further exporting of data obtained from there directly.

And as per Email Permissions documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) it clearly states that for App Developers

> Note: There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends.

As per the phone number, there is no access to it no matter what permission. You may though ask the user to fill those for you.